# Pair Apple Magic Keyboard with wireless dongle

Tags: usb, dock, bluetooth

Is it possible to pair an Apple Wireless Magic Keyboard with a USB receiver? I want this so that if I plug a laptop into my dock, the laptop will automatically connect to the keyboard (Not with Bluetooth)...

Comment: It’s a Bluetooth keyboard, it must connect via Bluetooth

Comment: A USB Bluetooth receiver or a USB WiFi receiver?